# Install component on redhawk

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, redhawksdr

I've just install the last release of RedHawk(1.10.2) on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, following RedHawk Manual. When I opened the Eclipse IDE, there is no component available, as instead occured on previous RedHawk for CentOS version.

Where can I find the component??Which packet can I download? How can I build them?

I also would like to work on USRP and I've already installed UHD. Where can I find an installer for using this device on RedHawk?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu source install of REDHAWK installs the [framework](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core), [bulkioInterfaces](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-bulkioInterfaces), [GPP](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-GPP), [CodeGen](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-codegen), [frontendInterfaces](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/frontendInterfaces), and [BurstIO](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/burstioInterfaces).  Other than the GPP, no components or devices are installed by default.

As jayemar mentioned, all of the components and devices that come packaged for CentOS are available as source on the [REDHAWK github page](https://github.com/redhawksdr).  For example a few of these include devices like the [USRP](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/USRP_UHD) and [RTL](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/RTL2832U), soft packages / libraries like [dsp](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/dsp) and [fftlib](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/fftlib), and components such as [PSD](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/psd), [TuneFilterDecimate](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/TuneFilterDecimate), [DataConverter](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/DataConverter) and [SigGen](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/SigGen).

Building and installing these components and devices from source can be done with the build script located in each repository or by going into the source folder (cpp/python/java) and issuing the "./reconf; ./configure; make; make install" commands.

Answer (score 0):

Components are installed to ${SDRROOT}/dom/components.  SDRROOT is set to /var/redhawk/sdr by default.  Any components installed there should show up in the IDE.

There are a lot of devices and components, including a USRP_UHD device, available on the RedhawkSDR Github repos:
https://github.com/RedhawkSDR